# phpMyAdmin и импорт из sql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Суть проблемы в следующем: 
-при импорте информации из моей локальной базы в базу созданную на хостинга возникает следующая ошибка. 
[image: результат импорта]

При этом пользователя к базе я создал. Могу редактировать инфу, но как только дела касается импорта (из csv-файла) случается ошибка приведённая выше.
Хостинг на котором я разместил базу hoster.by

Вот права юзера которого я добавил

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пользователь должен иметь не только права аутентификации и добавления данных в таблицу, но и право FILE. А также импортируемый файл должен располагаться в каталоге, указанном в @@secure_file_priv, если она установлена.

Comment: @Akina вот что мне разрешают делать

Comment: Это - ни о чём. Права FILE в списке нет. Читайте https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_file . Когда усвоите - обращайтесь в техподдержку хостинга и спрашивайте, есть ли возможность получить нужное право, и если да - как именно.

Comment: Но гораздо проще сделать обычный (.SQL) дамп и не заморачиваться.